# Why does AES encryption in C# is not decrpting accurately in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt AES encrpted json data.
The code is currently encrypted in c#.
I am able to decrypt the data but the first 10-15 charatcers are showing as unknown characters.
The code used for c# encrption is as follows:

```
public string Encryptword<T>(T Encryptval)
{
    SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
    byte[] password = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
    string IVString = "A@!B";
    byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(IVString);
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Encryptval);
    string encrypted = this.EncryptString(json, password, IV);
    return encrypted;
}
```

The PHP decryption code which i am using is as follows:

```
$password = 'xxxxxxx';
$method = 'aes-256-cbc';
$key = hash('sha256', $password, true);
$iv = mb_convert_encoding('A@!B', 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
$decrypted = trim(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_encode($iv)));
echo 'decrypted to: ' . $decrypted . "\n\n";
```

The Key and data are fine. The problem is with IV. Might be that i am doing some mistake in encoding the IV.

After decrption the json data error is as follows:

6"Su#cesRCod3":"11","CustomerDetails":{"Id":.................................

As you can see the { missing and Successcode is also distorted.

When I decrypt the code in dotnet. it works fine. But PHP code is not working accurate.

Comment: For starters you appear to be using string encoding for storing binary data. ASCII, UTF8, etc. conversions `byte[]` -> `string` -> `byte[]` will not give you the same `byte[]` as you started with for arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Please advice. How should i go with it in PHP?

Comment: I'd suggest base64, or hexadecimal, or some other encoding scheme intended for binary data.

Comment: I tried both base64 and hexadecimal for the IV text. Still the error is showing.

Comment: After binary conversions, PHP Aes throws errors like this --> IV passed is 27 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher.

Comment: You should post test data (key, plaintext, ciphertext) and the _complete_ code needed for reproduction, e.g. where `EncryptString` comes from.

Comment: Actually, The C# code is in 3rd party Client side. We are getting the encrypted code only which needs to be decrypted in my end in PHP. They have provided us the secret-key, IV text and encrypted data text.  Everything is working fine except the IV encoding. I just need to resolve the proces of encoding IV in PHP such that it matches the way it was encoded in C#

Comment: I think the issue of encoding lies in this part of C# --->byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(IVString);    please help in encoding the IV through PHP

Comment: In C#, `Encoding.UTF32` means UTF-32 in _little endian_ byte order. In the PHP code, try `UTF-32LE` instead of `UTF-32` in `mb_convert_encoding`.